# Android: determining if code should reside in activity or custom view

Tags: android

As I've been getting familiar with working with Activities and custom Views, I've been constantly having to decide where code that is relevant to both a View and it's parent Activity should go. Add in custom objects that need to be accessed by both, and the options on how to structure the code are endless. Here's the specifics of my issue:

**Relevant Classes/Files:**
*GameActivity* extends Activity: the layout it uses contains some custom Views.

*MapView* extends View: this is contained in the layout used by GameActivity

*World*: a custom class that defines a custom World object

**Expected Result:**

GameActivity pulls up the layout with MapView in it. The onDraw() function of the MapView draws a map on the canvas using information from a World object.

**Problem:**

The World object that the MapView needs is loaded from a previously saved file. I can get that object to the MapView in a number of different ways, and that's where I'm getting indecisive. I've gone through the following iterations. (Note, they all work. What I'm looking for is reasons to use one way over another.)

**Version1:**

*GameActivity*: all it does is setContentLayout(layout_with_mapview_in_it.xml)

*MapView*: has all the code for loading the World object from a file, and uses it to reference needed drawing parameters

*World*: a simple custom class w/ 3 parameters in its constructor

Then I decided that loading the World object from a file should be a method in the World class itself, instead of something that is done in the onCreate() method of the MapView. Since loading a world file is something you will never do without a World object, it makes sense that it should be class method. So I created a loadWorld(String world_name) method in the World class. Now the files looked like this:

**Version2:**

*GameActivity*: all it does is setContentLayout(layout_with_mapview_in_it.xml)

*MapView*: Creates a new World object using constructor, then calls it's loadWorld() method to update it with file info

*World*: a simple custom class w/ 3 parameters in it's constructor, and a loadWorld() method

Finally, I decided that only drawing activities should be in the MapView. The whole point of having a World object is to be able to pass it around, right? So I moved the World construction/loading out of the View and into the Activity. This resulted in having to create a setter method in the MapView to be able to pass the World object from the parent activity where it's getting created.

**Version3:**

*GameActivity*: sets layout, creates a World object and calls it's loadWorld() method to load it from the file. References the MapView by Id, then calls the setWorld() method of the MapView to pass the instance of the World object over

*MapView*: World object is set from outside. Draws the map using info from this object

*World*: a simple custom class w/ 3 parameters in it's constructor, and a loadWorld() method.

Ok, so that's where I'm currently at. My issue is that while I like the conventions I have picked in terms of having Views only contain drawing related code, and keeping class-related methods in their own classes- it seems when I switch to that method I'm suddenly creating temporary objects more often and passing objects from activity to activity to view and such. This seems like a lot more overhead, but at the same time that's the whole point of abstraction right? Abstract out a class so you can then instantiate an object from it and pass that around. Yet somehow it seems to me that the more I abstract out things, the more complex handling objects become.

I guess what I'm trying to ask here is, am I making things a ton more complicated by just not loading the World from the file in the MapView itself? Am I just being stubborn in not wanting to have code that involves reading object from a file in a View class? Is it any better to have it in its own class or in an Activity? What do I need to take into consideration when making these decisions? Is there a solution to my dilemma that I'm not even aware of?

I think the answer is going to be personal preference, but I want to get an idea if there are conventions out there to do it one way or the other, or if there are solid reasons why to structure a certain way. I've been trying to search for answers to this question, but I think I'm using the wrong search terms. I keep running across stuff that describes how to structure the activity/view structure, but nothing about the code inside. When there is code, it's inevitably someone teaching how to pass data between activities, or between an activity and view, etc. I know all those methods. I just don't know which one to use.

Some of the links I've been looking at:
[Android App with multiple views - Best Practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080287/android-app-with-multiple-views-best-practices)
[Android - Activities vs Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208445/android-activities-vs-views)
[Android Activities and Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318709/android-activities-and-views)
[Android: What is better - multiple activities or switching views manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072244/android-what-is-better-multiple-activities-or-switching-views-manually)

EDIT: More detail about App structure and code samples included

GameActivity:

```
/*IMPORT STATEMENTS REMOVED*/

public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);  
    Log.d("LOGCAT", "GameActivity Started");

    //get the world_name from MenuActivity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String world_name = intent.getStringExtra(MenuActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //load the world
    World world = loadWorld(world_name);

    //create a tilemap and get the tile translator array from it 
            //need to convert this to a static Map
    TileMap tileMap = new TileMap(this);    
    Map<Integer,Bitmap> tileTranslator = tileMap.getTileTranslator();

    //Create a reference to the MapView object and set the translator
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.setArgs(world, tileTranslator);

    //implement the OnTouchSwipeListener
    mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {

            /*CODE REMOVED*/
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public World loadWorld(String world_name) {

//Create a dummy world to load into - why?!
    World dummy_world = new World();

    //load the world 
    Log.d("LOGCAT", "Loading the World");
    try {
        World world = dummy_world.loadWorld(this, world_name);
        return world;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    //do nothing!
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException f) {
    //do nothing!
    }

    return dummy_world; //if world load fails, send back the default world
                        // NOTE: it's not saved!!!

}

}
```

MapView:

```
/*IMPORT STATEMENTS REMOVED*/

public class MapView extends View implements OnClickListener {

protected Context context;
public World world;
public Map<Integer,Bitmap> tileTranslator;

    //hardcoded variables for testing
private int tile_width = 50;
private int tile_height = 50;
public int screen_width = 12;
public int screen_height = 6;
public int playerX = 4;
public int playerY = 7;


public MapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    Log.d("LOGCAT", "MapView created"); 

    setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        /*CODE REMOVED*/
    }

//ugly method, need to break it out into individual setters
public void setArgs(World world, Map<Integer,Bitmap> tileTranslator){

    this.world = world;
    this.tileTranslator = tileTranslator;

}

}
```

World:

```
/*IMPORT STATEMENTS REMOVED*/

public class World implements Serializable {

public String world_name;
public int world_width;
public int world_height;
public int[][] world_map;

public World() { //default world - I don't even want this constructor here!

    world_name = "default_world";
    world_width = 1;
    world_height = 1;

    world_map = createWorld(world_width, world_height);

}

public World(String world_name, int world_width, int world_height) {

    //set the world attributes
    this.world_name = world_name;
    this.world_width = world_width;
    this.world_height = world_height;

    //generate the map
    world_map = createWorld(world_width, world_height);

}

private int[][] createWorld(int world_width, int world_height) {

    //create a local tile map 
    int[][] world_map = new int[world_width][world_height];

    //get a randomizer to fill the array with - {temporary solution}
    Random rand = new Random();

    //fill the tile map array with random numbers between 0 and 2
    for(int row = 0; row < world_map.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < world_map[row].length; col++) {
            world_map[row][col] = rand.nextInt(3);  //static number, needs variable!
                                                    //3 is the number of tile types
        }
    }

    return world_map;

}   

public void saveWorld(Context context, String world_name, World world) throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(world_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(world);
    oos.close();

}

public World loadWorld(Context context, String world_name) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(world_name);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    World world = (World)ois.readObject();

    /*this.world_name = world.world_name;
    this.world_width = world.world_width;
    this.world_height = world.world_height;
    this.world_map = world.world_map;*/  //why doesn't this work?
    return world;

}

}
```

Some code removed to save space. Let me know if any of the removed code or other Activities would be useful to see.

More details about what's going on behind the scenes:

The App starts with a MenuActivity, which has 2 buttons that each lead to another activity: WorldGenerationActivity or WorldSelectionActivity.

In WorldGenerationActivity, a user is shown a TextEdit screen and a button. They enter in parameters for the world they want to generate (world_name, world_width, world_height). Once they click the button, a World object is created and saved to a file using the given world_name as the file name. The file saving is done via a saveWorld(String world_name) method available in the World class. The instance of the newly created World object has it's saveWorld() method called, the file is saved, and the user is kicked back to the parent MenuActivity via a call to finish().

In WorldSelectionActivity, the user is shown a ListView that is plugged into an ArrayAdapter. An array of filenames is created from the files contained in the world saving directory, and the adapter enables the listview to display these filenames in a list. The user selects one and the selection is sent back to the parentMenuActivity as a string via an intent.putExtra(). WorldSelectionActivity is started for result, so it ends and we are back to MenuActivity.

Once MenuActivity gets the result back from WorldSelectionActivity, it stores the putExtra() message in a parameter and then calls GameActivity. It sends the message on to GameActivity via another putExtra().

GameActivity receives the message and stores it in a variable called world_name. It then creates a World object and passes the world_name string to the loadWorld(String world_name) method of the World class, which loads the specific World requested by the user earlier from a previous file save. I sort of glossed over how this is handled in my earlier explanation. Since I need a World object to load the world into, I am forced to first create a dummy World object in GameActivity, and then call its loadWorld method, and pass the result into yet another newly created World object. This resulted in my having to include a constructor with no parameters in the World class that I didn't want there. I'm not sure why I couldn't get it to work without created a dummy World first. I tried putting the file reading logic into the no-parameter constructor, but that didn't seem to work either. I think I'm missing something here but that's not my biggest concern at this point.

MapView is one of the views contained in GameView. The login in its onDraw() method requires information from a World object. I used to have all the World loading and constructing done here, and back then I only needed to create a World once and do whatever I wanted with it. Once I moved the loadWorld() method out of MapView and into the World class itself, and also moved the calling of that method out of MapView and into GameActivity, it seemed I was suddenly creating temporary World objects all over the place. I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to go about this and still keep things in the classes that make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your **version 3** is really better than the 2 others: your model (i.e. `World`) is independent from your your view (`MapView`) and your controller (`GameActivity`) bind them together.

I think you can improve the way your `World` object is created using the Builder pattern so that the job to create it is in a separate class. Let me show you what I mean :

```
public class WorldBuilder {

    private File worldFile;
    private String name = "default_world";
    private int width = 1;
    private int height = 1;

    public static WorldBuilder fromFile(File worldFile){
        WorldBuilder worldBuilder = new WorldBuilder();
        worldBuilder.worldFile = worldFile;
        return worldBuilder;
    }

    public WorldBuilder withName(String name){
        this.name= name;
        return this;
    }

    public WorldBuilder withWidth(int width){
        this.parameter2 = param2;
        return this;
    }

    public WorldBuilder withHeight(int height){
        this.height = height;
        return this;
    }

    public World build(){
        World world = new World(name,width,height);
        if(worldFile!=null)
            world.loadWorld(worldFile);
        return world;
    }    
}
```

In GameActivity, you can create the world with this single line of code:

```
World world = WorldBuilder.fromFile(worldFile)
        .withName(p1)
        .withWidth(p2)
        .withHeight(p3)
        .build();
```

And if you need to create a world with the default parameters you can simply write :

```
World world = WorldBuilder.fromFile(null).build();
```

**EDIT**

Where writing the code ?

All computation code than relies **only** on `World` data can be written in the `World` class. **Never** pass the `MapView` as an argument of a `World` method (keep the model independent from the view).

Try, as much as possible, to organize your code in such a way that computation is not done in `MapView`. The `MapView` must only contains code directly related to display.

Comment: I really like the Factory idea. I didn't even know about Factory method patterns until now. However, my World objects can be created 2 different ways. They have a standard constructor called from a different Activity. They are then saved to files in that Activity, so they can be loaded via file later. The World class has a standard constructor and a loadWorld() and saveWorld() method for the io stuff. With that in mind, does it still make sense to use a Factory method pattern?

Also, I already can create/load a World with a single line of code.

Updated OP with code and detailed app structure.

Comment: I do want to say thanks for the advice to keep other computation out of MapView. You can see in each subsequent version I am trying to get things more independent. It just seems when I do that I end up creating more temporary objects and passing things around more, and that feels less efficient. Maybe I'm just not used to juggling this much code around.

+1 for introducing me to the Factory method!

Comment: @user1944593 just updated my post to show how to use the Factory pattern with default values for the constructor.

Comment: I read up a little more on when/why to use Factories, and it's exactly what I need to clean up the parts of my code I'm unhappy with. I see now I won't even need the default world if I use the Factory method, since it's existence was dependent on how I was loading the world in the first place. Thank you for the elegant solution.

Comment: The answer is fine and all, but it messes up with the basic terms of the design patterns. What is demonstrated here is not an Abstract Factory pattern or Factory method pattern (these are two distinct patterns as well, and there is no just "Factory" pattern in old classic "Design Patterns" book). What is presented in the answer called a Builder pattern. Hint to comprehend the difference is the final method name - Build(). Just want to reduce the confusion and misunderstanding. The most correct source of truth: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=6oHuKQe3TjQC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT103#v=onepage

Answer (score -1):

Make your world class a singleton with several static methods that will retrieve necessary information.

Here is some crazy example:

```
public class World {
    private Rect mWorldAABB;
    private static World sInstance = null;
    private World() {
    // Put your code to read whatever you want from file
    };

    private static World getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
             sInstance = new World();
        }
         return sInstance;
    }

    private Rect getWorldRect() {
        return mWorldAABB;
    }
    public static Rect getWorldDimensions() {
        return getInstance().getWorldRect();
}
```

In this implementation you can access your "world" from both Activity and View via static method calls a-la World.getWorldDimensions().
The world instance is private and static. Also, due to lazy initialization it will be created and initialized only at first time when you request anything about the "world".  In this example, once you call World.getWorldDimensions(), getInstance() method will create the object of World class and any subsequent call to getWorldDimensions will re-use the object. 
So, basically, you can use this skeleton and add as many mode "public static" methods as you like.

Comment: Don't like it at all. Assume, one day, the app will handle more than one world. What will append ? Additionnaly, your code don't take care of constructor parameters and you assume that the file name can be hardcoded.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't explain it thoroughly in my OP, but the app is definitely handling more than one world that it will load from files. The current world instance being used by the app will need to be updated regularly based on user interaction and so cannot be static. Additionally, there will eventually be significantly more parameters contained in the object, so getter methods would become cumbersome

Comment: @ben75: okay, I see now. My first impression was that the World class is the only guy that handles it all. I mean the whole world computations and loading and initialization. I thought that the activity itself is no more than just a necessary android specific wrapper for the rest of the business logic. I guess I didn't read the description thoroughly, my bad ;). If you indeed have to play around with various worlds then the Factory pattern (as suggested) is good way to go.